# Horizontal Scroll View and layouts - Android

Tags: android, layout, horizontalscrollview

I'm new to android.

I would like a grid of image buttons on top of an image in a horizontal scroll view (phone in landscape mode) so that the background image and image buttons in the grid view scroll together

I thought something like Relative Layout, Horizontal Scroll View, Linear Layout(with background image), gridview (with rows and columns of image buttons)

I can't seem to overlay an image button on top of the image in the gridview. It only seems to work if I put an image button in the linear layout, but I need them in a grid. How do I go about this? Thanks in advance

If I try to put the image button in the grid view, I get render error:
addView(View,LayoutParams) is not supported in Adapter View

Maybe I should be using a grid layout?

```
Build.gradle (Module:app)
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.tim.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.
AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile
('proguard- android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

Comment: Think image of guitar fretboard, and trying to add buttons to the strings. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question is unclear , try to upload a picture of desired layout.

Anyway I can suggest  you to use a horizontal linear layout as parent and in that add vertical relative layout , so that you can have a button on one side and image on other side.

Comment: Think image of guitar fretboard, and trying to add buttons to the strings. Thanks

Comment: Then you can have a linear layout as parent and have as many as linear layouts as children of opposite orientation , you can have musical note symbols on each of them .

Comment: The above answer can be exact answer , as you are expecting a guitar strings

Comment: Where would you put the horizontal scroll view, as needs to be able to scroll?

Comment: "The above answer can be exact answer , as you are expecting a guitar strings."     Sorry I don't understand what you mean by this

Comment: If a question is unclear, you should not be answering it...